# OpenCV debugging/step into issue

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, opencv

I have the following issue in OpenCV: I have built the openCV libraries with CMake and compiled the OpenCV solution and the corresponding .pdb files were generated. I have a project that uses OpenCV library and I want to step into a function(cvStereoRectify) that crashes. I have included the symbols in my project (the folder were .pdb files are located) and when it hits the breakpoint at that function and I hit "Step Into" the error is generated and it doesn't go into the OpenCV source function. At runtime, the Modules window shows that opencv_calib3d.dll (and others opencv_*.dll) says that "Cannot find or open the PDB file".

Can someone show me the right way to do this ??
Thanks in advance,
Tamash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to step into openCV code  you have to copy the pdb  and the dll files to the location of your project.

in order to do so , go to your project properties , on the post build step type  the lines:

```
copy "C:\OpenCV2.31\CMake_Build\bin\Debug\*.dll"
 copy "C:\OpenCV2.31\CMake_Build\bin\Debug\*.pdb"
```

[image]

If that doesn't work , you'll have to include the  *h and *cpp  directories of the openCV library on your project setting:

On additional include directories type :

```
C:\OpenCV2.3\infustracture\Dienet;C:\OpenCV2.31\opencv\build\include;C:\OpenCV2.31\opencv\build\include\opencv;C:\OpenCV2.31\opencv\build\include\opencv2;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

[image]

Good luck